Flutter/Dart is it better to have multiple SQLite queries or list filters?
So I have an SQLite table users, this wont really be a massive table with millions of entries. I need to get 2 users and I know their IDs.
One way is to make 2 SQLite queries:
(pseudocode to illustrate my intention more concisely)
myUser1 = SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = myId1;
myUser2 = SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = myId2;

Another option is to get all the users and the filter them inside Dart:
users = SELECT * FROM users;
myUser1 = users.firstWhere((User user) => user.id! == myId1);
myUser1 = users.firstWhere((User user) => user.id! == myId2);

The 1st method is simpler and its the prettier one since i already have a getUserById() method, but it queries the DB twice.
The 2nd method does only 1 DB query and goes through the list of users twice.
Which one would be best from a speed standpoint? I feel like minimizing DB queries would probably save more time.

Third option is to use a single query that returns just the required users e.g. SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = myId1 or id = myId2 (or use WHERE id IN ('myId1','myId2') ).

Indeed, but the advantage of storing the whole list is that I can query it without additional DB queries (as long as no DB updates are performed). That is why I would like an answer to my actual question.
